# Alternatives to using request scope to label Ajax requests through the request stack in Coldfusion?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, coldfusion, scope, xmlhttprequest

I have a `Jquery Mobile` application. The first page requested by JQM is always a regular page load. All subsequent pages are pulled in via Ajax. As the user can start on every page, I need to put the full header on every page including all my custom stuff like (system error messages etc, etc.).

This is all loaded on the first page. On subsequent page loads `via AJAX` JQM still requests the full page, although only contents between the `div data-role="page"` are used.

So I was thinking to do this:

```
<cfset variables.xmlDetect = "">
    <cfset variables.headsUp = GetHttpRequestData()>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(variables.headsUp.headers, "X-Requested-With")>
        <cfset variables.xmlDetect = StructFind(variables.headsUp.headers, "X-Requested-With")>
    </cfif>
    <cfif variables.xmlDetect NEQ "">
        <cfset request.xmlDetected = "true">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset request.xmlDetected = "false">
    </cfif>
```

and set a flag for `this is requested via AJAX`, so I can cut down on the pageheader and everything else, because that will already have loaded on the first page.

I only read `request` scope is bad practive for passing info through the request stack. Is that so? I like the idea of `if request=xml, skip all of this, else serve it`. What would be the proper way to do this across templates and views without violating encapsulation? Just saves a ton of data being sent and dumped as soon as it arrives on the client.

Thanks for some toughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider moving this logic into a custom tag wrapper. The wrapper handles outputting the headers when necessary and has the check in it. You can see a full example of this on my blog: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/8/26/Making-jQuery-Mobile-templates-even-easier--with-ColdFusion

Comment: Let me expand on this - I forgot StackOverflow doesn't like it when I try to simply share a solution via the blog. Basically, I use a ColdFusion custom tag wrapper, ala: <cf_layout> stuff </cf_layout>. The custom tag uses the Ajax check to determine if it needs to output the "full" html or just the page div.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks. Two follow up questions: (a) Any worries about page caching? If the AJAXed page gets cached, is it likely that this page will be served as the "first" page from cache? (b) I'm also thinking about a way to use some sort of JQM templating, which would be available on/offline. You don't happen to have any blogposts about this, do you :-D? Thanks for chipping in!

Comment: a) Hmm. I don't think it will be an issue. To be honest, I've not tested this, but, my gut says no. b) Your question here kinda involves two different things - templating and online/offline support. Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Trying: I'm fiddling with JQM widgets to see if I can get them templated enough to work both on/offline. Take a JQM listivew for example, from which I would want to create a loopable template to be required on pagebeforeshow along with 2nd request for dynamic data to fill it with. The template could be generated server-side/served from CDN/manifest. Problem is: how to create templates that can be used client/server side? I'm trying [dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) with CFGroovy right now, but... stretching my knowledge, so I was hoping for one of your always handy blogposts :-)

Comment: I have to be honest, I still don't quite understand what you are asking here. If you are asking about supporting an offline web application, then you need to look into the HTML5 Application Manifest feature. This isn't tied to JQM or any other UI framework, it's a web feature in general and could be useful to you. Outside of that... unless you can clarify more, I don't know how to help. :)